# Celery: WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL)

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

I use Celery with RabbitMQ in my Django app (on Elastic Beanstalk) to manage background tasks and I daemonized it using Supervisor.
The problem now, is that one of the period task that I defined is failing (after a week in which it worked properly), the error I've got is:

```py
[01/Apr/2014 23:04:03] [ERROR] [celery.worker.job:272] Task clean-dead-sessions[1bfb5a0a-7914-4623-8b5b-35fc68443d2e] raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1168, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).
```

All the processes managed by supervisor are up and running properly (`supervisorctl status` says *RUNNNING*).

I tried to read several logs on my ec2 instance but no one seems to help me in finding out what is the cause of the `SIGKILL`. What should I do? How can I investigate?

These are my **celery settings**:

```py
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
BROKER_URL = os.environ['RABBITMQ_URL']
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = False
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
```

And this is my **supervisord.conf**:

```
[program:celery_worker]
environment=$env_variables
directory=/opt/python/current/app
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A com.cygora -l info --pidfile=/opt/python/run/celery_worker.pid
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=60
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/opt/python/log/celery_worker.stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stderr_logfile=/opt/python/log/celery_worker.stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
numprocs=1

[program:celery_beat]
environment=$env_variables
directory=/opt/python/current/app
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery beat -A com.cygora -l info --pidfile=/opt/python/run/celery_beat.pid --schedule=/opt/python/run/celery_beat_schedule
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=300
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
autostart=false
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/opt/python/log/celery_beat.stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stderr_logfile=/opt/python/log/celery_beat.stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=5MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
numprocs=1
```

---

### Edit 1

After restarting **celery beat** the problem remains.

### Edit 2

Changed `killasgroup=true` to `killasgroup=false` and the problem remains.

Comment: Hint: Most probably it's due to low memory/ram on your server. If you're running containers through docker command, you can see the memory consumption of each container using `docker stats`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The SIGKILL your worker received was initiated by another process. Your supervisord config looks fine, and the killasgroup would only affect a supervisor initiated kill (e.g. the ctl or a plugin) - and without that setting it would have sent the signal to the dispatcher anyway, not the child.

Most likely you have a memory leak and the OS's oomkiller is assassinating your process for bad behavior.

`grep oom /var/log/messages`. If you see messages, that's your problem.

If you don't find anything, try running the periodic process manually in a shell:

`MyPeriodicTask().run()`

And see what happens. I'd monitor system and process metrics from top in another terminal, if you don't have good instrumentation like cactus, ganglia, etc for this host.

Comment: You are right "celery invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0" ...now I have to find why this happen, because previously it was running as expected :P Thank you very much!

Comment: @daveoncode I think Lewis Carol once wrote, ""Beware the oom-killer, my son! The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!"

Comment: On my Ubuntu box the log to check is `/var/log/kern.log`, not `/var/log/messages`

Comment: in my Ubuntu box it is `/var/log/syslog` (so much for consistency)

Comment: @daveoncode how did you go about finding why that happens. im also stuck at a similar position. and the problem is its happening for only one task and the according to compute engine it everything about cpu usage and memory seems fine

Comment: I figured out it was a memory issue.

Comment: I was running celery workers on ecs with too little RAM per task and I also saw oom killing processes. So its not always related to memory leaks, but can also be the cause of not enough RAM.

Comment: @JSelecta Thanks. It really helped. The same issue was with my server. I was running multiple container on 1GB ram server. The celery worker needed 400MB for a specific task. When I upgraded to 2GB, it's working fine.

Answer (score 10):

One sees this kind of error when an asynchronous task (through celery) or the script you are using is storing a lot of data in memory because it leaks.

In my case, I was getting data from another system and saving it on a variable, so I could export all data (into Django model / Excel file) after finishing the process.

Here is the catch. My script was gathering 10 Million data; it was leaking memory while I was gathering data. This resulted in the raised Exception.

To overcome the issue, I divided 10 million pieces of data into 20 parts (half a million on each part). I stored the data in my own preferred local file / Django model every time the length of data reached 500,000 items. I repeated this for every batch of 500k items.

No need to do the exact number of partitions. It is the idea of solving a complex problem by splitting it into multiple subproblems and solving the subproblems one by one. :D