# Why does my Celery worker die with signal 6 - SIGIOT?

Tags: celery

I'm running a celery based application. Every now and then I see the following in the log:

> [... ERROR/MainProcess] Task
>   [...] raised unexpected: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 6
>   (SIGIOT).',) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1170,
>   in mark_as_worker_lost
>       human_status(exitcode)), WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGIOT).

Perhaps anyone can come up with an explanation for this?

Comment: I am having the same problem, and I am wondering the same question.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805079/celery-workerlosterror-worker-exited-prematurely-signal-9-sigkill